# Check box not working on touchscreen laptop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have checkbox like so

```
<div class="icheck" style="margin-top: 5px !important;">
   <input type="checkbox"
   name="param_{{ $item->id }}"
   d="param_{{ $item->id }}"
   value="1"
   class="checkListItem"
   @if ($item->value == 1) checked @endif> 
</div>
```

When checked it sets the value to 1 else to 0

```
$('body')
   .on('ifChecked', '.checkListItem', function(){
   $(this).val(1);
})

   .on('ifUnchecked', '.checkListItem', function(){
   $(this).val(0);
);
```

It works great on phones and computers if the computer isnt touchscreen. On touchscreen computers(except linux) it wont check the checkbox.

I tried on click tap event but its not working

```
$('.checkListItem').on('click tap', function(e){
    console.log("works");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Im kinda lost. Even more so because it works on touchscreen computers with linux. What could be the problem? How do I make the input type="checkbox" work on touchscreen computers?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using touchend instead of tap in your click function...Hope it will work...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```js
$('.radiogroup').on('click touchend',function(){
 console.log("works");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radiog" id="male" class="radiogroup" checked> Male
<input type="radio" name="radiog" id="femail" class="radiogroup"> Female
```

try `Touchstart` or `touchend` for touch device

```
$('.checkListItem').on('click touchstart touchend', function(e){
    console.log("works");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: if it is a touch devices then there are only three events `touchstart`
`touchmove`
`touchend`

Comment: I changed the $('.checkListItem') to the div wrapping it. And it responded. However the check mark isnt showing. Im guessing its not changing the value to checked. But its a start. Thanks!

Comment: Not really because the input value is not changing.

Comment: Now it is working check my answer I have tested on mobile also

Comment: On chrome dev tools - laptop with touch. Not working.